# Using a Helper method in a recursive sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics, timsort

I am trying to make a version of timSort in Java that uses the insertion after the array.length is < 10, otherwise is uses merge sort. Assuming my calls to insertionSort and merge are correct, what is keeping the following from hitting the insertion sort and properly timSorting?

```
/**
 * timSort is a generic sorting method that sorts an array of Comparable data
 * using the TimSort algorithm. Make sure this method is public so that we can
 * test it.
 * 
 * @param data The array of data to be sorted
 * @param      <E> The Generic Element.
 */
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void timSort(E[] data)
{
    timSortHelper(data, 0, data.length - 1);


}

/**
 * timSortHelper is a generic sorting method that sorts a sub-array array of
 * Comparable data using the TimSort algorithm. This method should be public for
 * testing purposes but would normally be private.
 * 
 * Ranges are specified with the parameters left and right, which are inclusive.
 * 
 * @param       <E> The Generic Element.
 * @param data  The array of data to sort
 * @param left  The index of the left-most position to sort
 * @param right The index of the right most position to sort
 */
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void timSortHelper(E[] data, int left, int right)
{
    // General Case: The sublist has at least one item in it.

    if ((right - left) >= 1)
    {

        int middle1 = (left + right) / 2;
        int middle2 = middle1 + 1;
        if (data.length < 10)
        {
            insertionSort(data);
        }
        else
        {
            timSortHelper(data, left, middle1);
            timSortHelper(data, middle2, right);

        }
        merge(data, left, middle1, middle2, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your program. That is by far the easiest way to find out if the problem is not immediately visible.

Comment: the debugger shows that it is selecting the correct indices but data.length is not being passed recursively as the smaller range. this is what i am having trouble understanding the recursive call passes in the smaller range of the sub-array yet when testing to see if length is < 10 it refers to the original array

Comment: Your method appears to work exactly as you describe, but you have formulated the problem differently than I suspect you meant to do.  In particular, `array.length` does not change during the recusion -- it's always the same property of the same array object -- so either your method will use Insertion Sort right away or it will never use it.  If you want to switch to Insertion Sort when working on small intervals of the array, then you want to be testing `right - left`.

Comment: So the second if statement is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Had to call a separate insertion sort that took the additional parameters for the adjusted indices